# Laravel preset React: problems encountered when `npm run dev` is executed

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

I have some issues with using React in Laravel 5.5. Every time I add or make changes to a component, I have to run `npm run dev` to compile the thing. When I do this the contents of css/app.css get reset, so I cannot write styles to this file.

Styles get unchanged if I have them in another CSS file, but I'd like to have my main styles written in css/app.css.

How can I do this?

Comment: You are not supposed to add styles on `css/app.css` file. That file is generated everytime you compile your assets.

Comment: @Jackowski sorry for a stupid question then, but if it's autogenerated every time assets are compiled then why it is even present?

Comment: Everytime you run `npm run dev` your styling assets are aggregated in one single file (`css/app.css`). This way in your html files you just need to add this file to the head of your document and you'll have access to all your styles.

Answer (score 1):

Keep all your css styles in a file in your resources directory and add the below code to end of your `webpack.mix.js` file.

```
mix.styles('path to your css file in resources directory', 'public/css/app.css');
```

If you are using `sass` use the below code

```
mix.sass('path to your css file in resources directory', 'public/css/app.css');
```

Also you no need to run `npm run dev` each time you make changes to your components. just run `npm run watch` and it will continuously look for changes and re-compile the components if anything is changed.